# .NET MAUI MenuBarItems will not work/display

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

When I put in the code for a MenuBarItem, nothing happens.  The app works, only where there's supposed to be a MenuBarItem, there's nothing.

MAUI-Android: manifest version 7.0.92/1.0.100
Visual Studio 2022, most recent update (Aug 30, 2023)

Here are the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/menu-bar)  for MenuBarItem.

The problem might be in this statement from the docs:

> .NET MAUI desktop apps will display a menu bar, containing menu items, when they are added to any [ContentPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.contentpage) that's hosted in a [NavigationPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.navigationpage) or a Shell app.

My code was lifted directly from this [Microsoft YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n48MiBh_SxM&t=421s).

```
MainPage.xaml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="P.MainPage" 
             Title="title">
      
      <ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
            <MenuBarItem Text="File">
                  <MenuFlyoutItem Text="DoSomething"
                                  Clicked="MenuFlyoutItemClicked" />
            </MenuBarItem>
      </ContentPage.MenuBarItems>

      <Grid>
            <Label Text="Hello there." />
      </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

```
MainPage.xaml.cs:

namespace P
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MenuFlyoutItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Hello from menu item.", "Yes", "No");
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, there's the "new-ing" of the MainPage itself.  As per that section mentioned above in the docs.

To address this, I need to take a look at where the MainPage is created, in *App.xaml.cs*.  The default code puts it in an AppShell, which -- to me -- satisfies the condition in the quote:

```
App.xaml.cs:

namespace P
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new AppShell();
        }
    }
}
```

However, just to be sure, I also changed the line:

```
MainPage = new AppShell();
```

To this:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

Shouldn't both lines work?  Neither change a thing.

I've plumbed the depths of the doc on MenuBarItems.  I don't know what else I could be doing wrong.

Here's what the MainPage looks like when I run it:
[image]

Comment: as you note, the docs say ".NET MAUI desktop apps" but you are not writing a desktop app

Comment: Oh, I'm such a dummy!!!

Answer (score 2):

From document [Display a menu bar in a .NET MAUI desktop app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/menu-bar),we could find that

> A .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) menu bar is a container that
> presents a set of menus in a horizontal row, at the top of an app on
> `Mac Catalyst` and `Windows`.

So, we can see the menu bar only on `Mac Catalyst` and `Windows`.